# How to insert 1000 blank rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have an empty table named tbl_emp. In this table I have more than 7 columns.

Columns are formatted like this:

```
Id, name, section branch, company, grade and so on.
```

Now I want to insert 1000 records, which only shows

```
1, 
2 
3, 
.,
. 
. 
1000
```

in id section as autoid.
But the other columns are blank.

Please help to insert such data.

Answer (score 4):

If `Id` is not an IDENTITY column then do this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_emp (Id, [name], sectionBranch /*etc etc*/)

SELECT TOP 1000
    Id = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    /*, etc etc*/
FROM
    master.dbo.spt_values
```

If `Id` is an IDENTITY column then try this

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_emp ON;

    INSERT INTO tbl_emp (Id, [name], sectionBranch /*etc etc*/)

    SELECT TOP 1000
        Id = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        /*, etc etc*/
    FROM
        master.dbo.spt_values


SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_emp OFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (If you keep Id as Auto Increment, you don't need to use @i in insert statement) :

```
declare @i int
set @i = 1

while (@i <=1000)
begin
     insert into tbl_emp values (@i, .....,.....)
     set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Comment: A loop is an inefficient choice. The bad habit of not specifying a column list for the insert statement is also highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

[Cool_Br33ze solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48640262/8242325) looks cool performance-wise, but here is mine:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(Id INT IDENTITY, Val VARCHAR(100))
```

---

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES (NULL)
GO 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cte as(
  select 1 as n, '' c1, '' c2, '' c3, '' c4, '' c5, '' c6, '' c7
  union all
  select n+1,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7 from cte where n < 1000
)

select * 
into my_table
from cte option (maxrecursion 1000)
```