# Create an empty table with default values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sybase

I need to create a table with empty spaces to be filled later and with default values in one column. Is that possible? I'm using SQL Server 2008

For example, I need something like this:

| Column A (empty) | Column B (with default values) |
| --- | --- |
| EMPTY/NULL | 101 |
| EMPTY/NULL | 102 |
| EMPTY/NULL | 103 |
| EMPTY/NULL | 104 |

and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sybase or SQL Server? Please only tag one RDBMS...

Comment: This may answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640068/how-to-insert-1000-blank-rows-in-sql-server/48640262

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert 1000 blank rows in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640068/how-to-insert-1000-blank-rows-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

do you mean this?

```
create table #temp(ColumnA varchar(32), ColumnB int identity(100,1))

insert into #temp(ColumnA) values(''), (''), (''), ('')

select * from #temp
```

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
|  | 100 |
|  | 101 |
|  | 102 |
|  | 103 |